# Filling one value multiple times in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `printcode` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `printbar` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1008 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want 1001 value in `printbar` column for 20 time single 
insert Query
Help

Comment: Don't understand the question! You have a table, show us mysqldump of what you want!

Comment: insert value 1001 in prinbar Field 20 time, how to insert command

Comment: Run `INSERT INTO printcode VALUES ('1001'); 20 times? I don't mean to be smart - are you looking for something like PostgreSQL's [generate_series()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-srf.html)?

Answer (score 2):

For relatively small sets of data you can simulate a series generator by querying a system catalog/table that has a number of rows that is greater than your desired set, eg:

```
insert into printcode (printbar)
select '1001'
from information_schema.columns
limit 20
```

- `information_schema.columns` is usually going to have at least a few 100 rows [`select count(*) from information_schmea.columns` to see how many rows your database has]
- we don't actually want anything from the catalog table other than a 'record'
- in this case we'll generate 20x rows of `1001`

Results of the above:

```
select printbar from printcode

printbar
--------
1001
1001
....
1001

Record Count: 20
```

Here's a [dbfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/42b7c/4)

From a cross join of 2-4 system catalog/tables it's possible to generate quite large sets of rows.

Answer (score 1):

In some application language, write a for loop.

In pure SQL (MySQL version),

```
INSERT INTO printcode (printbar) VALUES
    ('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),
    ('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),
    ('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),
    ('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001'),('1001') ;
```